# System-Wide Transparent Proxying Using URL Patterns

Tags: proxy, url, tor

Internet censorship -where I live- has almost turned web unusable so  I decided to setup a transparent proxy using Tor for my home network.
ince Tor is so slow -here- proxying all traffic through Tor would slow my connection to a crawl.  Therefore I need a mechanism to **selectively** proxy the traffic.

I know a bit of 'iptables' and it looks to me like the solution to my problem.  However there's a trick.  As most of the websites I need to access through Tor (like Google+, Facebook and such) use several IP addresses for their entry points, it's almost impossible for me to add 'iptables' rules for all of those IP addresses.  I need a mechanism to proxy the traffic based on URL patterns.  For example I need to be able to proxy access to '*.facebook.com' through Tor.

So the question boils down to:  how can I setup a system-wide transparent proxy using URL patterns?

Any idea/hint is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[Squid](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/FrontPage) might be what you want.

Squid out of the box configuration is generally ready to go as a proxy server, so the next thing you would need is an ACL like:

```
acl viator dstdomain .hotmail.com
```

So here you would include all the domains you want to proxy.

And you'll want the tor proxy defined:

```
cache_peer tor.proxy     parent    <tor port>       0
```

Then a command to direct traffic to tor, and prevent direct access for those domains, then let everything else through:

```
cache_peer_access tor.proxy allow viator
never_direct allow viator
always_direct allow !viator
```

Deployment of squid in your environment would require more information about your setup.

Comment: Thanks...I'll give this approach a try.
My installation is a vanilla 64bit ArchLinux.
Just one question:  If I get Squid to work, will it operate as a transparent proxy or I should set the proxy in any program I'm using?

Comment: _UPDATE:_ I got Squid + iptables working as a transproxy.  Now the only obstacle is making Squid use Tor.  The lines you provided are not working -perhaps I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @BahmanMovaqar Great!  So far so good.  What happens in the squid logs?

Comment: Actually there isn't anything neither in `access.log` nor in `cache.log` that indicates anything has connected to `squid` unless I use `squidclient`; I'm just judging based on the blazing fast speed of page reloads after `squid` was setup :-)  Perhaps would be nice if you could please help me find a way to make sure `squid` is working -other than hunch :-)  TIA,

Comment: I found out how to increase the log level of `squid`.  So here is the [squid.conf](http://pastebin.com/PVdzaMqu) and this is the resulting [cache.log](http://pastebin.com/2Wx1cmKv).

Comment: That log shows less than a minute of results, and I can't see any browsing activity in it.  The log level is probably set too high, as it will be hard to see what is going on.  I think you should ignore transparent mode while trying to get this working and set your browser to use squid in the proxy settings.

Comment: I decreased the log level.  This is [cache.log](http://pastebin.com/hwzHpugr) and this is [access.log](http://pastebin.com/J8WEApaA) after I load a non-filtered web page by setting proxy settings in Firefox.  However when I try to load a filtered web page like facebook.com using the same proxy settings it doesn't work: [access.log](http://pastebin.com/q6NM0dqW).  Note that the addressed is defined in `viator` rule.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### You don't *have* to install and use an additional proxy server, of course.

Selecting a HTTP proxy server according to the pattern of the URL is exactly what proxy-auto-configuration scripts do, after all.

### Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2004). [*Automatic proxy HTTP server configuration in web browsers*](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/web-browser-auto-proxy-configuration.html). Frequently Given Answers.

Comment: Thanks but I need a system-wide transparent proxy which applies to any program using the internet not just only the browser.